# simple codeigniter query + results display won't display

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to display data from my database in a Codeigniter view. Seems like it should be simple, but it's just not working.

I'm getting 2 errors: undefined variable ($movielist, in the view) and invalid argument for php foreach, also in the view.

Any idea how I can get this to work? Code below.

**Controller**

```
function displayMovies() {

$this->load->model('movie_list_model');

$data['movielist'] = $this->movie_list_model->getList();

$this->load->view('movielist_view', $data);
}
```

**Model**

```
function getList() {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT firstname, lastname, favorite_movie FROM movies');
        return $query->result();


        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
             echo $row['firstname'];
             echo $row['lastname'];
             echo $row['favorite_movie'];
        }   
    }
```

**View**

```
      <?php foreach($movielist as $mlist)
        {
            echo  $mlist->firstname . '<br />'; 
            echo  $mlist->lastname . '<br />'; 
            echo  $mlist->favorite_movie; 
        }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If( the query doesn't find any rows, it will return `null`, resulting in the `undefined` error in your view. The invalid argument error is because you can't iterate through `null`.

A safety would be including something like this in your view:

```
if($movielist)
{
    /* foreach() {} */
}
```

Also, your model should only return data (not echo it).

```
function getList() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT firstname, lastname, favorite_movie FROM movies');
    return $query->result(); /* returns an object */
    // Alternatively:
    // return $query->result_array(); /* returns an array */
}
```

I also recommend using [Active record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html):

```
function getList() {
    $this->db->select('firstname');
    $this->db->select('lastname');
    $this->db->select('favorite_movie');

    $query = $this->get('movies');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am no longer getting the "invalid argument for php foreach"--I added the if statement you suggested. But I am still getting the "undefined variable" for $movielist. Any idea why that variable is not recognized as defined?